# Phone turning over to mute

Tags: android

I'm doing an android app that has a media player working on notifications as a service , and I want to be able to mute/stop that service, When the phone is turned over or the screen is covered.

Can anyone give me pointers how to implement This, many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ProximitySensor to detect when the phone screen is covered. Here is an example: [Using proximity sensor in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967806/using-proximity-sensor-in-android)

Comment: @SanadZuhdiAlHassan glad to hear :)