# How to detect use the STREAM_VOICE_CALL or the audio speaker in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, audio, speaker

Take audio play in whatsapp as example, if your ear near the phone, the speaker will change to the earphone speaker, while the ear leave the phone, it use the audio speaker.

I am using the mediaplayer to play the audio file, and found that there is

```
 setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
```

to switch the speaker to the ear speaker. and

```
 setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
```

for default audio speaker.

The problem is , how to detect when the ear is near the phone, or is it necessary to implement by my program (should have some default android API for that ? )

Thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most (or may be all?) android devices have proximity sensor. I think it is what you need.
Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967806/using-proximity-sensor-in-android) and Android documentation on [Sensor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html) for more details.